# Smooth wrapper background-image transition, when using React onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events on a childs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-image

My page have a 4 sections on view port:

[image]

I need implement smooth background image transition when hovering on each section.
In my React-Next app, im using  onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave events on childs, to handling
wrapper className changing, so image changing to. Full working code on codesandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/bg-image-opacyty-biwx1?file=/pages/index.js:1239-1251)

How can i achieve smooth transition when hovering on each child, of CSS do not have property background-opacity?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the background opacity, but there will be a workaround solution.
For example:

```
.has-background-element {
  position: relative;
  & > * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  &::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('');
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  &:hover {
    &::before {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

In case you need to set the background image dynamically, should replace `&:before` by a specific element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have resolve this by adding one more class for background, and gave to him background: url(/some-img) - jpg with main background color.